# Can I extend panic alarm cable with cat5e and a soldering iron

Tags: electrical, wiring, alarm, extension

Currently have one of these installed on a wall, but I want to mount it to the underside of a desk as it looks a bit ugly:
[image]
I need to extend the alarm cable in order to reach the desk, however I don’t really want to buy a whole reel of alarm cable. Can I simply solder the wires of the alarm cable to some leftover cat5e and heatshrink it and put it in an electrical box?

Comment: Did you originally install it or did an alarm company install it? If you're paying for a service, you shouldn't mess with it, check with the company so you don't void any guarantees.

Comment: Most likely an alarm company installed it, however it was already installed when we moved into the building

Comment: Any experience with soldering thin wires ?

Comment: Done a few small hobby electronics projects before, although any additional advice would be appreciated!

Comment: How is the cable currently connected to the box? hard wired? RJ45 jack? (typical for ethernet).  If RJ45, I'd just get a RJ45 jack and terminate the existing cable there. Then use a pre-made cable of the appropriate length with the plugs already connected to go from the box to the newly installed termination jack.   Also, depending upon how sensitive the alarm box is makes a difference.  CAT-5 is UTP (unshielded twisted pair)  The twisting of the wires inside the cable cancel out cross talk, opening up the existing cable enough to solder on the new one may interfere with the signal, or not!

Comment: The main concern would be accidentally setting off the alarm while messing with the wires. If it’s a normally-open loop, accidentally shorting the wires together will look like pressing the button. If it’s normally closed, disconnecting the switch will look like pressing the button. Best to call the monitors company and tell them to disregard the sensor while you’re working on it.

Answer (score 4):

A panic switch is not going to need a lot of current, so cat5 (or even doorbell wire) should be fine to extend it.

Cat5 is typically insulated with (raw) PVC which is melty, so soldering will be tricky,  but that can be mitigated by using extra heatshrink.  alarm cable is typically crosslinked PVC which is less melty.

I'd consider using a screw terminal RJ45 block in the place of the existing switch
then plugging an RJ45 in there to connect the CAT-5 cable. especially if the new furniture is even slightly portable.

[image]

If you want to prevent accidental unplugs shorten the unlocking lever on the RJ45 plug, meaning that a pointed tool will now be needed to unplug the cable.

Answer (score 0):

### Possible problem with wires

The Cat-5 is typical 22-24 AWG

The alarm cable is typical 18 AWG or less (much thicker)

Connecting those two together will create a problem, of not enough current carrying.

**Possible problem with soldering**

It look simple but it is tricky to do it right

[image: solder]

To cold not enough contact

Too hot will melt the insulation way beyond wanted and the solder will flow far up the wire.

### Alternative method

is to use Butt Splice Heat Shrinks with Crimp tool. Tool need Crimp tool found at Home Depot.

[image: crimp]

Please be aware that you do not need to buy 500 foot on the roll. Most stores will cut it to your length at a cost of about $0.30 per foot.

Example: [by the foot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southwire-By-the-Foot-18-2-Gray-Stranded-CU-CL3R-Shielded-Security-Cable-57573199/204725192)

Comment: Most wire/cable can be bought at certain lengths also, if you want some extra to play with.  10, 30, 50ft(just examples) lengths usually easy to find.  Nice if you measure 8ft but find you really need 8 ft 5inches.

Comment: @crip659 thank you for confirming my answer

Comment: You can buy wire online in just about any length you want and have it shipped free. If you find 30 vendors expect at least 29 different prices.